# requrejs module always undefined with knockout.bindings

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, requirejs

I am trying to load some knockout custom bindings in my code and 90% of the time it will come with error: "Message: undefined is not a function". Once in a blue moon it will work.

Note: i reverted back to require.js version 2.1.9 vs. 2.1.11, and the success of loading the custom binding module goes up. Basically more success with 2.1.9, but still happens.

Here is what I am doing:

I have a **app.index.js** file:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "../Scripts/app/views/administrator/directhire",
    paths: {
        "app.index": "app.index",
        "spinner": "../../../helpers/spinner",
        "domReady": "../../../../lib/domReady",
        "ko": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min",
        "knockout.validation": "../../../../lib/knockout.validation",
        "mapping": "../../../../lib/knockout.mapping-latest.debug",
        "directHireHomeViewModel": "../../../viewModels/directHireHomeViewModel",
        "bootDatepicker": "../../../../lib/bootstrap-datepicker",        
        "jquery": "//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min",
        "toastr": "../../../../lib/toastr",
        "model.navigation": "../../../models/model.navigation",
        "model.directhire": "../../../models/model.directhire",
        "datepicker.bindings": "../../../../lib/koBindings/datepicker.bindings"
    },
    shim: {
        "knockout.validation": ["ko"],
        "mapping": ["ko"],
        "datepicker.bindings": ["bootDatepicker"]
    }
});
require(["ko"], function (ko) {
    //manually set the global ko property
    window.ko = ko;

    //then bring in knockout validation
    require(["knockout.validation"], function () {
        ko.validation.configure({
            insertMessages: false,
            decorateElement: true,
            errorElementClass: 'error'
        });
        // Load the main app module to start the app
        require(["domReady", "main.index"], function (domReady, bs) {
            domReady(function () {
                bs.run();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

and **main.index.js** file:

```
define(['ko', "mapping", 'spinner', 'directHireHomeViewModel', 'model.navigation', 'model.directhire', 'bootDatepicker', 'datepicker.bindings'],
    function (ko, mapping, spinner, directHireHomeViewModel, Navigation, DirectHire, bootDatepicker, dateBindings) {
    var
        vm = new directHireHomeViewModel(),
        run = function () {
            spinner.start();
            $.getJSON("api call", function (data) {
                mapping.fromJS(data, {
                    create: function (options) {
                        return new Navigation(options.data);
                    }
                }, vm.navigations);
            });

            $.getJSON("api call", function (data) {
                mapping.fromJS(data, {
                    create: function (options) {
                        return new DirectHire(options.data);
                    }
                }, vm.directhires);
            }).done(function () {
                ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById('#administrator-direct-hire'));
                spinner.goByeBye();
            });            
        };
    return {
        run: run
    };
});
```

here is the **custom binding**:

```
define('datepicker.bindings', ['bootDatepicker', 'ko'], function (bootDatepicker, ko) {
     ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
         init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
             //initialize datepicker with some optional options
             console.log($(element));
             var mod = require('bootDatepicker');
             console.log(require.defined('bootDatepicker'));
             console.log($(element).datepicker());
             var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
             $(element).datepicker(options).on("changeDate", function (ev) {
                 var observable = valueAccessor();
                 observable(ev.date);
             });
         },
         update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
             var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
             if (value != "" && value != "1/1/0001") {
                 $(element).datepicker("setDate", value);
             }
         }
     };
 });
```

This error only occurs on knockout custom bindings. I some cases if I have more then one custom bindings, it will fail on one or the other. i.e. datepicker.bindings fails one time, and colorpicker.bindings fails the next time.

Comment: What line gives you the error you mention at the start of your question?

Comment: In the datepicker.bindings at $(element).datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least you need a shim for `bootDatepicker` because it depends on jQuery:

```
bootDatepicker: ["jquery"]
```

Without this shim you'd get exactly what you've reported in your question. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not work, and when it does not work `$(...).datepicker` is undefined.

I looked at the source but it is not clear to me whether it would also need to have Bootstrap's JS code loaded. I guess if your GUI is working when `bootDatepicker` is loaded correctly, you don't need it.

Comment: I see. So technically you could this:

define('datepicker.bindings', ['jquery','bootDatepicker', 'ko'], function ($,bootDatepicker, ko) {